# How to check if a list of matrix contains a given matrix in Maple

Tags: maple

I have some problems in Maple.

If I have a matrix:

```
Matrix1 := Matrix(2, 2, {(1, 1) = 31, (1, 2) = -80, (2, 1) = -50, (2, 2) = 43});
```

I want to decide if it is in the below list:

```
MatrixList := [Matrix(2, 2, {(1, 1) = 31, (1, 2) = -80, (2, 1) = -50, (2, 2) = 43}), Matrix(2, 2, {(1, 1) = -61, (1, 2) = 77, (2, 1) = -48, (2, 2) = 9})];
```

I did the following:

```
evalb(Matrix1 in MatrixList);
```

but got "false".

> Why? And how do I then make a program that decide if a matrix is
>   contained in a list of matrices.

Comment: Carl's good answer should get you there. A brief explanation of why your original approach failed is that mutable data structures such as Matrices do not get recognized as identical objects (under `evalb` comparison). Which is a good thing. A more flexible (and more complicated) test (if the entries are close floats, say) might be to use http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=verify/Matrix&term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a much cheaper way than DrC's

**ormap(LinearAlgebra:-Equal, MatrixList, Matrix1)**